# Integrate User-login and registration of wordpress with existing PHP website

Tags: wordpress

I have an existing php portal - www.oureducation.in. now I was integrating a wordpress answers theme to it on www.oureducation.in/answers .

Now, I need to do following things
- Register a user on wordpress when a user registers on mysite. this I have done using triggers.
- login only from mysite. If a user logs in on mysite, he should be logged in on wordpress as well.(I tried doing this but with a lot of errors)
- logout from mywebsite and user should be logged out from wordpress as well.(user session_destroy but not working properly.)
-logout from wordpress and user shall be logged out from my site as well.(not at all working)

I thing i have made a whole mess of it. So i want to start from start. please guide me how to carry out these integration.

> I have been through this link -http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website
>   but not of much help to me.

Added following code to wp theme`s functions.php

```
add_action( 'setup_theme', 'wp_session_oureducation' );

function wp_session_oureducation() {
    global $wpdb;

if( !$current_user->data->ID ) {
        if( !empty ($_SESSION['User_id'] ) ) {
            $fetchidquery = "Select ID from $wpdb->users where user_email = '".$_SESSION['E-mail']."'";
            $thisuserid = $wpdb->get_row($fetchidquery);
            wp_set_current_user( $thisuserid->ID,'');
            $user_id = $thisuserid->ID; 
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_session_oureducation_head' );

function wp_session_oureducation_head() {
global $wpdb;
    if( !$current_user->data->ID ) {
         if( !empty ( $_SESSION['User_id'] ) ) {
             $fetchidquery = "Select ID from $wpdb->users where user_email = '".$_SESSION['E-mail']."'";
             $thisuserid = $wpdb->get_row( $fetchidquery );
             wp_set_current_user( $thisuserid->ID,'');
             $user_id = $thisuserid->ID; 
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: @Alxandr i have edited the question and added the code i have used.